# Android Firebase Realtime database error when getting a nodes children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a pretty weird problem. This code was working a few days ago however now it is crashing my application. I am trying to loop through a nodes children.

```
private void getInfo()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("ForumResponses").child(forumID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                ForumResponses forumResponses = snap.getValue(ForumResponses.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

If i remove the below line of code the application does not crash. Why is this?

```
ForumResponses forumResponses = snap.getValue(ForumResponses.class);
```

Below is error log

```
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertInteger(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:351)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:272)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:197)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:178)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:580)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:550)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:420)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:214)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:212)
    at Activities.ViewForumResponseActivity$1.onDataChange(ViewForumResponseActivity.java:95)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Below is Forum Response Class

```
public class ForumResponses
{
private String id;
private String response;
private String author;
private String authorID;
private String usersWhoLiked;

private int liked;

public ForumResponses()
{
    /*
    Default no arg constructor
     */
}

public ForumResponses(String id, String response, String author, String authorID, String usersWhoLiked, int liked)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.response = response;
    this.author = author;
    this.authorID = authorID;
    this.usersWhoLiked = usersWhoLiked;
    this.liked = liked;
}

public String getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getResponse()
{
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(String response)
{
    this.response = response;
}

public String getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author)
{
    this.author = author;
}

public String getAuthorID()
{
    return authorID;
}

public void setAuthorID(String authorID)
{
    this.authorID = authorID;
}

public String getUsersWhoLiked()
{
    return usersWhoLiked;
}

public void setUsersWhoLiked(String usersWhoLiked)
{
    this.usersWhoLiked = usersWhoLiked;
}

public int getLiked()
{
    return liked;
}

public void setLiked(int liked)
{
    this.liked = liked;
}
```

}

Below is image of database

[image]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also add your database structure.

Comment: No problem, edited post

Comment: Please also add the content of the children under `-620048878` and the content of your `ForumResponses` class.

Comment: added that image

Comment: Please also ad the content of your `ForumResponses` class as asked also before.

Comment: This class just contains public no arg constructor with getter and setter methods.

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: Class added to post.

Comment: 'liked' is not an int (as defined in your class) but a hashmap (as depicted in your database image - or a child class implementation).

Comment: I will write you an answer right away.

Comment: The problem was with "liked" thank you for yer help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int

Because the type of your `liked` field inside your `ForumResponses` class is `int` and in your database as the field is actual an object. To solve this, either convert the field in the database to `int` or change the type of the field in your `ForumResponses` class to a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Thank you very much